Cheerio cannot read "href" attribute of element even though it exists in source code
I am trying to create a scraper for a second hand website of PS5 games. For this I am using Cheerio to parse over the result list. In some cases it is able to read the URL properly, in other cases it cannot read it.
The HTML is very similar.
Here are two examples of the HTML for a PS5 game listing.
The first one does NOT work, while the second one does work properly.
<li class="hz-Listing hz-Listing--list-item">
   <div class="hz-Listing-listview-content">
      <div class="hz-Listing-item-wrapper">
         <a class="hz-Link hz-Link--block hz-Listing-coverLink" tabindex="0" href="/v/games-en-spelcomputers/games-sony-playstation-5/m2118704624-call-of-duty-black-ops-cold-war-ps5?correlationId=88f930ec-2dba-41b7-8c3d-572b8e9932c3">
            <figure class="hz-Listing-image-container">
               <div class="hz-Listing-image-item hz-Listing-image-item--main"><img title="Call Of Duty Black Ops Cold War PS5, Games en Spelcomputers, Games | Sony PlayStation 5, Ophalen of Verzenden, Zo goed als nieuw" alt="Call Of Duty Black Ops Cold War PS5, Games en Spelcomputers, Games | Sony PlayStation 5, Ophalen of Verzenden, Zo goed als nieuw" data-src="https://images.2dehands.com/api/v1/listing-twh-p/images/ee/ee63c7dc-e07a-46a7-9d44-214573e0102b?rule=ecg_mp_eps$_83" src="https://images.2dehands.com/api/v1/listing-twh-p/images/ee/ee63c7dc-e07a-46a7-9d44-214573e0102b?rule=ecg_mp_eps$_83" loading="lazy" decoding="async"></div>
            </figure>
            <div class="hz-Listing-group">
               <div class="hz-Listing-group--title-description-attributes">
                  <h3 class="hz-Listing-title">Call Of Duty Black Ops Cold War PS5</h3>
                  <div class="hz-Listing-price-extended-details">
                     <p class="hz-Listing-price hz-Listing-price--mobile hz-text-price-label">€&nbsp;30,00</p>
                     <div class="hz-Listing-details-button">
                        <div tabindex="0"><span>details</span><i class="hz-Icon hz-Icon--m hz-Icon--textSecondary hz-SvgIcon hz-SvgIconArrowDown" aria-hidden="true" data-sem="Icon"></i></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="hz-Listing-description hz-text-paragraph">Call of duty black ops cold war ps5</p>
                  <div class="hz-Listing-trust-items-and-attributes">
                     <div class="hz-Listing-bottom-info-divider-wrapper">
                        <hr class="hz-Divider hz-Listing-bottom-info-divider">
                        <div class="hz-Listing-attributes"><span class="hz-Attribute hz-Attribute--default">Zo goed als nieuw </span><span class="hz-Attribute hz-Attribute--default">Ophalen of Verzenden </span></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="hz-Listing-group--price-date-feature"><span class="hz-Listing-price hz-Listing-price--desktop hz-text-price-label">€&nbsp;30,00</span><span class="hz-Listing-date hz-Listing-date--desktop">Vandaag</span><span class="hz-Listing-priority hz-Listing-priority--all-devices"><span> </span></span></div>
               <details class="hz-Listing-extended-content" open="">
                  <summary></summary>
                  <div class="hz-Listing-extended-attributes"><span class="hz-Attribute">Ophalen of Verzenden </span><span class="hz-Attribute">Zo goed als nieuw </span></div>
                  <p class="hz-Listing-description">Call of duty black ops cold war ps5</p>
               </details>
            </div>
         </a>
         <div class="hz-Listing--sellerInfo">
            <span class="hz-Listing-seller-name-container"><a class="hz-Link hz-Link--isolated hz-TextLink" tabindex="0"><span class="hz-Listing-seller-name">Hamed</span></a></span><span class="hz-Listing-location"><span class="hz-Listing-distance-label">Antwerpen</span><span class="hz-Listing-distance">6 km</span></span>
            <div class="hz-Listing-group--price-date-feature hz-Listing-group--price-date-feature--tablet"><span class="hz-Listing-date">Vandaag</span><span class="hz-Listing-priority hz-Listing-priority--all-devices"><span> </span></span></div>
         </div>
         <div class="hz-Listing-group--mobile-bottom-row">
            <div><span class="hz-Listing-location"><span class="hz-Listing-distance-label">Antwerpen&nbsp;· </span><span class="hz-Listing-distance">6 km</span></span></div>
            <div><span class="hz-Listing-priority hz-Listing-priority--all-devices"><span> </span></span><span class="hz-Listing-date hz-bottom-right">Vandaag</span></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
<li class="hz-Listing hz-Listing--list-item">
   <div class="hz-Listing-listview-content">
      <div class="hz-Listing-item-wrapper">
         <a class="hz-Link hz-Link--block hz-Listing-coverLink" data-tracking="9t5G0nLzJjAb7jB4_m1LMJ29I6e103y6utea-cQ2VyvZfKrzq9f_HhFRcQs51D7DDd-SoqGagw9D54hu4Pycc7yjZ5mpfCBPwRMkGaSpLVR60CZ2ogNhny8EYEPAf59qdU1ikBwGvYxMB4wUKpKrGZvBwzDWJaTxVbO5vfkYjtnwR7zkvvXw3T1vWN6fSLfiiRe9XhBiPRvrTdjiwdGKZlTq66CuBS20DpLeymIx2P8GhkfITk5fI2hexOI_WcHenwtHfLq3vmt9Un3Kr9C49pOW-7m4kcQ4Ho-Ifq6yE8N3V8l03u7hxVNvPcFfE5EIhC7JcIxxNippEmMsgqEc84wAgzxPbBhFrIgOjuNG4QFMhX4JAeL6ctQX3tLg0PLM3M1j8kjwnncRzbJsAhq__Cdkah3xxx8H7FnTtCznFH85uQ_q4WGZP0yDu0Noqf2eT9Isz7IdZsu7n2JTycOtYJNSqYh_rw98aObanOBFbq4cGAfx4VL59dg-5Da2jVeEAievaqqPDEowDjIRoCvo_3RUniHbp_XmHmItZGVMifc1Iuth8fKFQ4RgkP967hWAyBld2ecZv9uVaS1xB7FFqFzgnuC2c4iApQ4LX5vIwPc" href="/v/games-en-spelcomputers/games-sony-playstation-5/a136918897-final-fantasy-xvi-ps5-playstation-5-ps5-games?c=efb2ef4dc323389c4f92ed10afa33e3a&amp;casData=9t5G0nLzJjAb7jB4_m1LMJ29I6e103y6utea-cQ2VyvZfKrzq9f_HhFRcQs51D7DDd-SoqGagw9D54hu4Pycc7yjZ5mpfCBPwRMkGaSpLVR60CZ2ogNhny8EYEPAf59qdU1ikBwGvYxMB4wUKpKrGZvBwzDWJaTxVbO5vfkYjtnwR7zkvvXw3T1vWN6fSLfiiRe9XhBiPRvrTdjiwdGKZlTq66CuBS20DpLeymIx2P8GhkfITk5fI2hexOI_WcHenwtHfLq3vmt9Un3Kr9C49pOW-7m4kcQ4Ho-Ifq6yE8N3V8l03u7hxVNvPcFfE5EIhC7JcIxxNippEmMsgqEc84wAgzxPbBhFrIgOjuNG4QFMhX4JAeL6ctQX3tLg0PLM3M1j8kjwnncRzbJsAhq__Cdkah3xxx8H7FnTtCznFH85uQ_q4WGZP0yDu0Noqf2eT9Isz7IdZsu7n2JTycOtYJNSqYh_rw98aObanOBFbq4cGAfx4VL59dg-5Da2jVeEAievaqqPDEowDjIRoCvo_3RUniHbp_XmHmItZGVMifc1Iuth8fKFQ4RgkP967hWAyBld2ecZv9uVaS1xB7FFqFzgnuC2c4iApQ4LX5vIwPc">
            <figure class="hz-Listing-image-container">
               <div class="hz-Listing-image-item hz-Listing-image-item--main"><img title="Final Fantasy XVI - PS5 (Playstation 5 (PS5) Games), Games en Spelcomputers, Games | Sony PlayStation 5, Nieuw, Verzenden" alt="Final Fantasy XVI - PS5 (Playstation 5 (PS5) Games), Games en Spelcomputers, Games | Sony PlayStation 5, Nieuw, Verzenden" data-src="https://twhbe.images.icas.io/api/v1/4f9d6f39/images/d5/d5ed7529-0549-4ef2-8e9f-787ee77ca37f?rule=eps_83" src="https://twhbe.images.icas.io/api/v1/4f9d6f39/images/d5/d5ed7529-0549-4ef2-8e9f-787ee77ca37f?rule=eps_83" loading="lazy" decoding="async"></div>
            </figure>
            <div class="hz-Listing-group">
               <div class="hz-Listing-group--title-description-attributes">
                  <h3 class="hz-Listing-title">Final Fantasy XVI - PS5 (Playstation 5 (PS5) Games)</h3>
                  <div class="hz-Listing-price-extended-details">
                     <p class="hz-Listing-price hz-Listing-price--mobile hz-text-price-label">€&nbsp;39,99</p>
                     <div class="hz-Listing-details-button">
                        <div tabindex="0"><span>details</span><i class="hz-Icon hz-Icon--m hz-Icon--textSecondary hz-SvgIcon hz-SvgIconArrowDown" aria-hidden="true" data-sem="Icon"></i></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="hz-Listing-description hz-text-paragraph">Final fantasy xvi - ps5 bij happy gamer hebben we een breed assortiment in allerlei retro en moderne games. Gepolijste games met g</p>
                  <div class="hz-Listing-trust-items-and-attributes">
                     <div class="hz-Listing-bottom-info-divider-wrapper">
                        <hr class="hz-Divider hz-Listing-bottom-info-divider">
                        <div class="hz-Listing-attributes"><span class="hz-Attribute hz-Attribute--default">Nieuw </span><span class="hz-Attribute hz-Attribute--default">Verzenden </span></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="hz-Listing-group--price-date-feature"><span class="hz-Listing-price hz-Listing-price--desktop hz-text-price-label">€&nbsp;39,99</span><span class="hz-Listing-date hz-Listing-date--desktop">Vandaag</span><span class="hz-Listing-priority hz-Listing-priority--all-devices"><span> </span></span></div>
               <details class="hz-Listing-extended-content" open="">
                  <summary></summary>
                  <div class="hz-Listing-extended-attributes"><span class="hz-Attribute">Nieuw </span><span class="hz-Attribute">Verzenden </span></div>
                  <p class="hz-Listing-description">Final fantasy xvi - ps5 bij happy gamer hebben we een breed assortiment in allerlei retro en moderne games. Gepolijste games met garantie! - Tweedehands games met de kwaliteit van eerstehands! - Morgen in huis vanaf €2,50 - 2 maanden garantie! -...</p>
               </details>
            </div>
         </a>
         <div class="hz-Listing--sellerInfo">
            <span class="hz-Listing-seller-name-container"><a class="hz-Link hz-Link--isolated hz-TextLink" tabindex="0"><span class="hz-Listing-seller-name">HappyGamer</span></a></span><span class="hz-Listing-location"><span class="hz-Listing-distance-label">Heel België</span></span>
            <div class="hz-Listing-group--price-date-feature hz-Listing-group--price-date-feature--tablet"><span class="hz-Listing-date">Vandaag</span><span class="hz-Listing-priority hz-Listing-priority--all-devices"><span> </span></span></div>
            <span class="hz-Listing-seller-link"><a class="hz-Link hz-Link--isolated hz-Listing-sellerCoverLink hz-TextLink" tabindex="0" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow"><span>Bezoek website</span></a></span>
         </div>
         <div class="hz-Listing-group--mobile-bottom-row">
            <div><span class="hz-Listing-seller-external-link"><a class="hz-Link hz-Link--isolated hz-Listing-sellerCoverLink hz-TextLink" tabindex="0" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow"><span>Bezoek website</span></a></span></div>
            <div><span class="hz-Listing-priority hz-Listing-priority--all-devices"><span> </span></span><span class="hz-Listing-date hz-bottom-right">Vandaag</span></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>

My code is this:
let baseUrl = 'https://www.2dehands.be'
const url = baseUrl + '/l/games-en-spelcomputers/games-sony-playstation-5/'
const result = []
axios.get(url)
    .then((res) => {
    const html_data = res.data
    const $ = cheerio.load(html_data);

    const gamesList = ".hz-Listings"
    const gamesItems = $(gamesList).find('li.hz-Listing.hz-Listing--list-item')

    $(gamesItems).each((idx, val) => {
      let titleElement = $(val).find('.hz-Listing-title');
      if (titleElement && titleElement.length > 0) {
        let title = titleElement.text()
        console.log('title is:', title)
      }

      let urlContainer = $(val).find('.hz-Listing-item-wrapper');
      if (urlContainer && urlContainer.length > 0) {
        let aElement = urlContainer.find('a');
        let url = aElement.attr('href');
        console.log('url is:', url);
      }
    })
  })

And it returns the following:
idx is: 31
title is: Call Of Duty Black Ops Cold War PS5
url is: undefined
-------------

idx is: 32
title is: Final Fantasy XVI - PS5 (Playstation 5 (PS5) Games)
url is: /v/games-en-spelcomputers/games-sony-playstation-5/a136918897-final-fantasy-xvi-ps5-playstation-5-ps5-games

I tried putting this in a jsFiddle, but I am getting CORS error so i'm not sure if it's possible to put it in a jsFiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/uyfL6pro/

The site you're working with is a single page app using Next.js. There's a script tag <script id="__NEXT_DATA__"> that contains a JSON dump of all of the site's data. Rather than working with the DOM, I suggest working with that JSON dump, which lets you get the data you want (and much more) without the unreliability and complexity of the DOM layer in the way:
axios
  .get(url)
  .then(({data: html}) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(cheerio.load(html)("#__NEXT_DATA__").text());
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null ,2));

    const {listings} = data.props.pageProps.searchRequestAndResponse;

    for (const e of listings) {
      console.log({title: e.title, url: e.vipUrl});
    }
  });

Although it appears to include duplicate info, there's also a topBlock key you can merge with listings if you want to get closer to your scrape:
const {listings, topBlock} = data.props.pageProps.searchRequestAndResponse;

for (const e of [...topBlock, ...listings]) {
  console.log({title: e.title, url: e.vipUrl});
}

A rule of thumb with scraping is: always go as close to the data source as you can--it's easier and more reliable. In order of priority:

API requests with key
direct API requests to a public endpoint
JSON data payload inside a script (used here)
Non-JSON JavaScript object data inside a script
the DOM

If the data is loaded asynchronously, you can sometimes use an automated browser and intercept responses to avoid the DOM.

Wow! I learned something new today! Thank you so very much!
